# How do i check a file has been uploaded?

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

I am using [ASPUpload](http://www.aspupload.com/object_upload.html#Files) to do file uploads for a web form, the current form i am working on updates a record in the database so you have the option to change the filename, i have the following check

```
If Upload.Form("imageFilename-bound") <> "" And Upload.Files = null Then
    skipUpload = true
End If
```

when the page is loaded, the filename in database is made to be the value of a read-only text box `imageFilename-bound` while the file input field `imageFilename` is used to select a file. so the Psudo Code of the above is

> **IF** *[our previous image name] is not empty* **AND** *[we have not received a
>   file to upload]* **THEN** 
>          *{We are not uploading a file}*

now since there is the option that the user doesn't want to change the file and file upload has only recently been suggested (after the form was completed) i don't want to change to much so anything to do with file uploading (including validation of size, type etc) i have put in a `If skipUpload = false Then` condition.

If i remove the `And Upload.Files = null` part i don't get any errors however when updating and i do go to change the image it doesn't do it (as imageFilename-bound is not a blank string thus the if statement is correct) however when i add the `And Upload.Files = null` part i get a 500 error and thus i can't actully see the problem (i am forced to test on a machine which has no error logging)

So my question is, how do i check with ASPUpload if my file input field did receive a file?

Answer (score 0):

i have got the page to work with this code

```
skipUpload = false

If Upload.Form("imageFilename-bound") <> "" Then
    skipUpload = true
    For Each File in Upload.Files
        skipUpload = false
    Next
End If
```

Psudo:

> **IF** *[our previous image name] is not empty* **THEN** 
>           *{We are not uploading a file}* 
>           **FOR EACH** *[Submitted file]* 
>                   *{we actually are going to be uploading}*

this does what i want but i feel this is very inelegant, having to use a Loop to check if i have submitted any file. i am still looking for a better answer

Comment: It should be as simple as `skipUpload = (Len(Upload.Form("imageFilename-bound"))>0) And (Upload.Files.Count>0)`.